# Getting information out a json sting

Tags: php, json

I am attempting to work with JSON in PHP and I was wondering if someone could help me out getting me to the $events=>$url when the information is returned from json_decode. What is the variable path. There are a number of looping record in the return data and I am using something like:

```
$data = json_decode($feeds,true);
    foreach($data as $item=>$events) {
                    $date = $events=>$month.'/'.$events=>$day.'/'.$events=>$year;
                    $events.='<li><span class="engindate">'.$date.'</span><br /><span class="source">'.$item["title"].'</span><br /><a href="'.$item["url"].'">'.$item["details"].'</a></li>';  
                }
```

Here is the JSON sample (yes, I know it is incomplete)

```
{
  "month": 5,
  "year": 2013,
  "events": [
    {
      "url": "http://www.engin.umich.edu/college/about/cal/events/2013/may/shavuot-ends",
      "id": "shavuot-ends",
      "month": 5,
      "year": 2013,
      "day": 16,
      "startTime": "1:42",
      "endTime": "1:42",
      "hideTime": "true",
      "deadline": "true",
      "am_pm": "pm",
      "am_pm_start": "pm",
      "am_pm_end": "pm",
      "title": "Shavuot ends",
      "location": "",
      "details": "Shavuot runs from May 14 to May 16.",
      "host": "Michigan Engineering",
      "event_type": "Holiday",
      "image": {
        "src": "http://www.engin.umich.edu/++resource++umich_images/default_event.jpg",
        "alt": "Shavuot ends"
      }
    },...
```

Comment: `foreach($data->events as $item)`

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Just now saw the `true` parameter on `json_decode` (why?). So `foreach($data['events'] as $item)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed up your `->` and `=>` operators. Try like this:

```
$data = json_decode($feeds,true);
    foreach($data['events'] as $event) {
                    $date = $event['month'].'/'.$event['day'].'/'.$event['year'];
                    $events.='<li><span class="engindate">'.$date.'</span><br /><span class="source">'.$event["title"].'</span><br /><a href="'.$event["url"].'">'.$event["details"].'</a></li>';  
                }
```

Comment: One more quick question. If I wanted to get one item out of the list of events by its index, would it be something like $event[0]['month']?

Answer (score 1):

`$data['events']['url']`

The array is multidimensional.

```
foreach($data as $key=>$item) {
    if($key=='events') {
        $url = $item['url'];
    }
}
```

or

```
foreach($data['events'] as $key=>$item) {
    if($key=='url') {
        $url = $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I assign the value of $data to item in a foreach loop would it be $item['events']['url']? foreach($data as $item)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$data = json_decode($feeds);

$eventsHtml = "";
foreach($data->events as $event ) {
                    $date = $data->month.'/'.$event->day.'/'.$data=>year;
                    $eventsHtml .='<li><span class="engindate">'.$date.
                                  '</span><br /><span class="source">'.
                                   $event=>title.
                                   '</span><br /><a href="'.$event=>url.'">'.
                                   $event->details.'</a></li>';  
                }
```

You have an object "`data`". This has a member "`month`", so this is `$data->month`
It has a member "`events`" which is an array. The first event is `$data->events[0]`. If you iterate with a `foreach`, this is `foreach($data->events as $event ) {` having `$event` as the one event.

Basic errors:

```
$events=>$month // is inproper syntax
foreach($data as $item=>$events) {
        ..
        $events.= // this would overwrite the iterator variable above ??
```